# Next/Previous buttons query using sharepoint online rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We wanted to integrate the Next and pervious buttons in a page where on click on Next button we frame a rest api which gets next 10items from the SharePoint list on click on previous button it need to show previous 10items.

Example to get Next 10 items
we tried using **?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=10&$top=10** to Next 10 items--without orderby field

we tried using **?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_Order=10&p_ID=10&$top=10** to Next 10 items--with orderby field

This 2 scenarios are working fine.
Bit confused how to create query to get the previous 10 items?

Comment: Which REST API are you using? Can you update your question with what's in front of the "?"?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:set the current request URL to a variable when clicking the next button, when the users click the previous button, just request the URL saved in the variable.

Method 2:Calculate the id of the previous request based on the id of the item currently displayed, and splice it into the request url.